# C++ How to add second screen(for 2FA) in Credential Provider V1?

Tags: c++, multi-factor-authentication, windows-credential-provider

Hi, I am working on wrapping existing credential provider in Windows 10. I have used Sample Code from https://github.com/Stexir/CredentialProvider/tree/501d955f02535b58bf10e09f3f3edaefa7a77fe8/samplewrapexistingcredentialprovider. I have modified this code so it shows no other fields:

common.h

```
#include <credentialprovider.h>
#include <ntsecapi.h>
#define SECURITY_WIN32
#include <security.h>
#include <intsafe.h>

#define MAX_ULONG  ((ULONG)(-1))

// The indexes of each of the fields in our credential provider's appended tiles.
enum SAMPLE_FIELD_ID 
{
    SFI_TILEIMAGE             = 0,
    SFI_NUM_FIELDS            = 1,  // Note: if new fields are added, keep NUM_FIELDS last.  This is used as a count of the number of fields
};

// The first value indicates when the tile is displayed (selected, not selected)
// the second indicates things like whether the field is enabled, whether it has key focus, etc.
struct FIELD_STATE_PAIR
{
    CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_FIELD_STATE cpfs;
    CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_FIELD_INTERACTIVE_STATE cpfis;
};

// These two arrays are seperate because a credential provider might
// want to set up a credential with various combinations of field state pairs 
// and field descriptors.

// The field state value indicates whether the field is displayed
// in the selected tile, the deselected tile, or both.
// The Field interactive state indicates when 
static const FIELD_STATE_PAIR s_rgFieldStatePairs[] = 
{
    { CPFS_DISPLAY_IN_BOTH, CPFIS_NONE },                   // SFI_TILEIMAGE
};

// Field descriptors for unlock and logon.
// The first field is the index of the field.
// The second is the type of the field.
// The third is the name of the field, NOT the value which will appear in the field.
static const CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_FIELD_DESCRIPTOR s_rgCredProvFieldDescriptors[] =
{
    { SFI_TILEIMAGE, CPFT_TILE_IMAGE, L"Image" },
};
```

CSampleCredential.cpp

```
#ifndef WIN32_NO_STATUS
#include <ntstatus.h>
#define WIN32_NO_STATUS
#endif
#include <unknwn.h>
#include "CSampleCredential.h"
#include "CWrappedCredentialEvents.h"
#include "guid.h"

// CSampleCredential ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// NOTE: Please read the readme.txt file to understand when it's appropriate to
// wrap an another credential provider and when it's not.  If you have questions
// about whether your scenario is an appropriate use of wrapping another credprov,
// please contact credprov@microsoft.com

CSampleCredential::CSampleCredential():
    _cRef(1)
{
    DllAddRef();

    ZeroMemory(_rgCredProvFieldDescriptors, sizeof(_rgCredProvFieldDescriptors));
    ZeroMemory(_rgFieldStatePairs, sizeof(_rgFieldStatePairs));
    ZeroMemory(_rgFieldStrings, sizeof(_rgFieldStrings));

    _pWrappedCredential = NULL;
    _pWrappedCredentialEvents = NULL;
    _pCredProvCredentialEvents = NULL;

    _dwWrappedDescriptorCount = 0;
    _dwDatabaseIndex = 0;
}

CSampleCredential::~CSampleCredential()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(_rgFieldStrings); i++)
    {
        CoTaskMemFree(_rgFieldStrings[i]);
        CoTaskMemFree(_rgCredProvFieldDescriptors[i].pszLabel);
    }

    _CleanupEvents();

    if (_pWrappedCredential)
    {
        _pWrappedCredential->Release();
    }

    DllRelease();
}

// Initializes one credential with the field information passed in. We also keep track
// of our wrapped credential and how many fields it has.
HRESULT CSampleCredential::Initialize(
    __in const CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_FIELD_DESCRIPTOR* rgcpfd,
    __in const FIELD_STATE_PAIR* rgfsp,
    __in ICredentialProviderCredential *pWrappedCredential,
    __in DWORD dwWrappedDescriptorCount
    )
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // Grab the credential we're wrapping for future reference.
    if (_pWrappedCredential != NULL)
    {
        _pWrappedCredential->Release();
    }
    _pWrappedCredential = pWrappedCredential;
    _pWrappedCredential->AddRef();

    // We also need to remember how many fields the inner credential has.
    _dwWrappedDescriptorCount = dwWrappedDescriptorCount;

    // Copy the field descriptors for each field. This is useful if you want to vary the field
    // descriptors based on what Usage scenario the credential was created for.
    for (DWORD i = 0; SUCCEEDED(hr) && i < ARRAYSIZE(_rgCredProvFieldDescriptors); i++)
    {
        _rgFieldStatePairs[i] = rgfsp[i];
        hr = FieldDescriptorCopy(rgcpfd[i], &_rgCredProvFieldDescriptors[i]);
    }
    return hr;
}

// LogonUI calls this in order to give us a callback in case we need to notify it of 
// anything. We'll also provide it to the wrapped credential.
HRESULT CSampleCredential::Advise(
    __in ICredentialProviderCredentialEvents* pcpce
    )
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    _CleanupEvents();

    // We keep a strong reference on the real ICredentialProviderCredentialEvents
    // to ensure that the weak reference held by the CWrappedCredentialEvents is valid.
    _pCredProvCredentialEvents = pcpce;
    _pCredProvCredentialEvents->AddRef();  

    _pWrappedCredentialEvents = new CWrappedCredentialEvents();

    if (_pWrappedCredentialEvents != NULL)
    {
        _pWrappedCredentialEvents->Initialize(this, pcpce);

        if (_pWrappedCredential != NULL)
        {
            hr = _pWrappedCredential->Advise(_pWrappedCredentialEvents);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY; 
    }

    return hr;
}

// LogonUI calls this to tell us to release the callback.   
// We'll also provide it to the wrapped credential.
HRESULT CSampleCredential::UnAdvise()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    if (_pWrappedCredential != NULL)
    {
        _pWrappedCredential->UnAdvise();
    }

    _CleanupEvents();

    return hr;
}

// LogonUI calls this function when our tile is selected (zoomed)
// If you simply want fields to show/hide based on the selected state,
// there's no need to do anything here - you can set that up in the 
// field definitions. In fact, we're just going to hand it off to the
// wrapped credential in case it wants to do something.
HRESULT CSampleCredential::SetSelected(__out BOOL* pbAutoLogon)  
{
    HRESULT hr = E_UNEXPECTED;

    if (_pWrappedCredential != NULL)
    {
        hr = _pWrappedCredential->SetSelected(pbAutoLogon);
    }

    return hr;
}

// Similarly to SetSelected, LogonUI calls this when your tile was selected
// and now no longer is. We'll let the wrapped credential do anything it needs.
HRESULT CSampleCredential::SetDeselected()
{
    HRESULT hr = E_UNEXPECTED;

    if (_pWrappedCredential != NULL)
    {
        hr = _pWrappedCredential->SetDeselected();
    }

    return hr;
}

// Get info for a particular field of a tile. Called by logonUI to get information to 
// display the tile. We'll check to see if it's for us or the wrapped credential, and then
// handle or route it as appropriate.
HRESULT CSampleCredential::GetFieldState(
    __in DWORD dwFieldID,
    __out CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_FIELD_STATE* pcpfs,
    __out CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_FIELD_INTERACTIVE_STATE* pcpfis
    )
{
    HRESULT hr = E_UNEXPECTED;

    // Make sure we have a wrapped credential.
    if (_pWrappedCredential != NULL)
    {
        // Validate parameters.
        if ((pcpfs != NULL) && (pcpfis != NULL))
        {
            // If the field is in the wrapped credential, hand it off.
            if (_IsFieldInWrappedCredential(dwFieldID))
            {
                hr = _pWrappedCredential->GetFieldState(dwFieldID, pcpfs, pcpfis);
            }
            // Otherwise, we need to see if it's one of ours.
            else
            {
                FIELD_STATE_PAIR *pfsp = _LookupLocalFieldStatePair(dwFieldID);
                // If the field ID is valid, give it info it needs.
                if (pfsp != NULL)
                {
                    *pcpfs = pfsp->cpfs;
                    *pcpfis = pfsp->cpfis;

                    hr = S_OK;
                }
                else
                {
                    hr = E_INVALIDARG;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            hr = E_INVALIDARG;
        }
    }
    return hr;
}

// Sets ppwsz to the string value of the field at the index dwFieldID. We'll check to see if 
// it's for us or the wrapped credential, and then handle or route it as appropriate.
HRESULT CSampleCredential::GetStringValue(
    __in DWORD dwFieldID, 
    __deref_out PWSTR* ppwsz
    )
{
    HRESULT hr = E_UNEXPECTED;

    // Make sure we have a wrapped credential.
    if (_pWrappedCredential != NULL)
    {
        // If this field belongs to the wrapped credential, hand it off.
        if (_IsFieldInWrappedCredential(dwFieldID))
        {
            hr = _pWrappedCredential->GetStringValue(dwFieldID, ppwsz);
        }
        // Otherwise determine if we need to handle it.
        else
        {
            FIELD_STATE_PAIR *pfsp = _LookupLocalFieldStatePair(dwFieldID);
            if (pfsp != NULL)
            {
                //hr = SHStrDupW(_rgFieldStrings[SFI_I_WORK_IN_STATIC], ppwsz);
            }
            else
            {
                hr = E_INVALIDARG;
            }
        }
    }
    return hr;
}

// Returns the number of items to be included in the combobox (pcItems), as well as the 
// currently selected item (pdwSelectedItem). We'll check to see if it's for us or the 
// wrapped credential, and then handle or route it as appropriate.
HRESULT CSampleCredential::GetComboBoxValueCount(
    __in DWORD dwFieldID, 
    __out DWORD* pcItems, 
    __out_range(<,*pcItems) DWORD* pdwSelectedItem
    )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(dwFieldID);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pcItems);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pdwSelectedItem);
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

// Called iteratively to fill the combobox with the string (ppwszItem) at index dwItem.
// We'll check to see if it's for us or the wrapped credential, and then handle or route 
// it as appropriate.
HRESULT CSampleCredential::GetComboBoxValueAt(
    __in DWORD dwFieldID, 
    __in DWORD dwItem,
    __deref_out PWSTR* ppwszItem
    )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(dwFieldID);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(dwItem);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(ppwszItem);
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

// Called when the user changes the selected item in the combobox. We'll check to see if 
// it's for us or the wrapped credential, and then handle or route it as appropriate.
HRESULT CSampleCredential::SetComboBoxSelectedValue(
    __in DWORD dwFieldID,
    __in DWORD dwSelectedItem
    )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(dwFieldID);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(dwSelectedItem);
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

//------------- 
// The following methods are for logonUI to get the values of various UI elements and 
// then communicate to the credential about what the user did in that field. Even though
// we don't offer these field types ourselves, we need to pass along the request to the
// wrapped credential.

HRESULT CSampleCredential::GetBitmapValue(
    __in DWORD dwFieldID, 
    __out HBITMAP* phbmp
    )
{
    HRESULT hr;
    if ((SFI_TILEIMAGE == dwFieldID) && phbmp)
    {
        HBITMAP hbmp = LoadBitmap(HINST_THISDLL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_TILE_IMAGE));
        if (hbmp != NULL)
        {
            hr = S_OK;
            *phbmp = hbmp;
        }
        else
        {
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        hr = E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    return hr;
}

HRESULT CSampleCredential::GetSubmitButtonValue(
    __in DWORD dwFieldID,
    __out DWORD* pdwAdjacentTo
    )
{
    HRESULT hr = E_UNEXPECTED;

    if (_pWrappedCredential != NULL)
    {
        hr = _pWrappedCredential->GetSubmitButtonValue(dwFieldID, pdwAdjacentTo);
    }

    return hr;
}

HRESULT CSampleCredential::SetStringValue(
    __in DWORD dwFieldID,
    __in PCWSTR pwz
    )
{
    HRESULT hr = E_UNEXPECTED;

    if (_pWrappedCredential != NULL)
    {
        hr = _pWrappedCredential->SetStringValue(dwFieldID, pwz);
    }

    return hr;

}

HRESULT CSampleCredential::GetCheckboxValue(
    __in DWORD dwFieldID, 
    __out BOOL* pbChecked,
    __deref_out PWSTR* ppwszLabel
    )
{
    HRESULT hr = E_UNEXPECTED;

    if (_pWrappedCredential != NULL)
    {
        if (_IsFieldInWrappedCredential(dwFieldID))
        {
            hr = _pWrappedCredential->GetCheckboxValue(dwFieldID, pbChecked, ppwszLabel);
        }
    }

    return hr;
}

HRESULT CSampleCredential::SetCheckboxValue(
    __in DWORD dwFieldID, 
    __in BOOL bChecked
    )
{
    HRESULT hr = E_UNEXPECTED;

    if (_pWrappedCredential != NULL)
    {
        hr = _pWrappedCredential->SetCheckboxValue(dwFieldID, bChecked);
    }

    return hr;
}

HRESULT CSampleCredential::CommandLinkClicked(__in DWORD dwFieldID)
{
    HRESULT hr = E_UNEXPECTED;

    if (_pWrappedCredential != NULL)
    {
        hr = _pWrappedCredential->CommandLinkClicked(dwFieldID);
    }

    return hr;
}
//------ end of methods for controls we don't have ourselves ----//


//
// Collect the username and password into a serialized credential for the correct usage scenario 
// (logon/unlock is what's demonstrated in this sample).  LogonUI then passes these credentials 
// back to the system to log on.
//
HRESULT CSampleCredential::GetSerialization(
    __out CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE* pcpgsr,
    __out CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION* pcpcs, 
    __deref_out_opt PWSTR* ppwszOptionalStatusText, 
    __out CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON* pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon
    )
{
    HRESULT hr = E_UNEXPECTED;

    if (_pWrappedCredential != NULL)
    {
        hr = _pWrappedCredential->GetSerialization(pcpgsr, pcpcs, ppwszOptionalStatusText, pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon);
    }

    return hr;
}

// ReportResult is completely optional. However, we will hand it off to the wrapped
// credential in case they want to handle it.
HRESULT CSampleCredential::ReportResult(
    __in NTSTATUS ntsStatus, 
    __in NTSTATUS ntsSubstatus,
    __deref_out_opt PWSTR* ppwszOptionalStatusText, 
    __out CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON* pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon
    )
{
    HRESULT hr = E_UNEXPECTED;

    if (_pWrappedCredential != NULL)
    {
        hr = _pWrappedCredential->ReportResult(ntsStatus, ntsSubstatus, ppwszOptionalStatusText, pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon);
    }

    return hr;
}

BOOL CSampleCredential::_IsFieldInWrappedCredential(
    __in DWORD dwFieldID
    )
{
    return (dwFieldID < _dwWrappedDescriptorCount);
}

FIELD_STATE_PAIR *CSampleCredential::_LookupLocalFieldStatePair(
    __in DWORD dwFieldID
    )
{
    // Offset into the ID to account for the wrapped fields.
    dwFieldID -= _dwWrappedDescriptorCount;

    // If the index if valid, give it the info it wants.
    if (dwFieldID < SFI_NUM_FIELDS)
    {
        return &(_rgFieldStatePairs[dwFieldID]);
    }

    return NULL;
}

void CSampleCredential::_CleanupEvents()
{
    // Call Uninitialize before releasing our reference on the real 
    // ICredentialProviderCredentialEvents to avoid having an
    // invalid reference.
    if (_pWrappedCredentialEvents != NULL)
    {
        _pWrappedCredentialEvents->Uninitialize();
        _pWrappedCredentialEvents->Release();
        _pWrappedCredentialEvents = NULL;
    }

    if (_pCredProvCredentialEvents != NULL)
    {
        _pCredProvCredentialEvents->Release();
        _pCredProvCredentialEvents = NULL;
    }
}
```

and got first screen:[Initial Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8Hy0.png). 

It logs in successfully when I provide username and password. I do not want direct login even if correct information is provided but create new field that will ask for second factor(e.g., static pass code).

Since I am beginner, I need to know what must be done in above Credential Provider files to add second screen for pass code field. 

 Any help/suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question and provide a specific question and provide a code sample showing your problem. At least provide the code with the modifications made. Otherwise its impossible to help.